How do I get the index of the container holding a label?
I am trying to get the index of a container holding a label so I can store the location in a database, retrieve the location and place the label at the same position on a different screen. I am trying to use the following code to get the index so I don't have to create a looksup table. I get method getComponentIndex in class com.codename1.ui.Container cannot be applied to given types;. Has anyone worked around this problem? lwpos is an int and lbllw is a label.
lwpos = lbllw.getParent().getComponentIndex();


That code won't compile but this will:
lwpos = lbllw.getParent().getComponentIndex(lbllw);

However, I don't think this approach is necessarily what you would want to do as component indexes are fragile. I suggest giving components names using something like:
lbllw.setName("MyLabel");

Then in runtime you can do something similar to this:
public Component findByName(String name, Container rootContainer) {
    for(Component c : rootContainer) {
        if(name.equals(c.getName())) {
            return c;
        } 
        if(c instanceof Container) {
            Component result = findByName(name, (Container)c);
            if(result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}


I am getting to my testing, and I am getting the "component cannot be converted to a container" error. I am not finding any information about finding a container by name within another container. Main container has 360 added containers within it. I am placing the label based on capturing the location of the label after a drag. Thanks.

I'm guessing you're trying to cast a component to a container within the hierarchy but without the code and the error from the console I can't pinpoint that. You can post a new question which will let you go include additional information or if it's relevant to this code you can edit the question to include the additional information.
